# Confused about the "Print in Order" problem on LeetCode

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

This should be an easy problem on multithreading: https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/
*"The same instance of Foo will be passed to three different threads. Thread A will call first(), thread B will call second(), and thread C will call third(). Design a mechanism and modify the program to ensure that second() is executed after first(), and third() is executed after second()"* And they give this code:

```
public Foo() {}
    public void first(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException {
        // printFirst.run() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
        printFirst.run();
    }
    public void second(Runnable printSecond) throws InterruptedException {
        // printSecond.run() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
        printSecond.run();
    }
    public void third(Runnable printThird) throws InterruptedException {
        // printThird.run() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
        printThird.run();
    }
```

**Seems I can solve it using Thread.join as below, but what I don't understand is why they pass the instance of Runnable to each method, and how to properly do it because the below code will print each message twice - once because Thread.start() will invoke the corresponding run() method, and once from calling that method directly. I understand that this is the wrong way to do it, but can't figure out what is the right solution, if we try to utilize the join method. **

````
public Foo() throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r1 = () -> {
            System.out.println("first ");
        };
        first(r1);
        
        Runnable r2 = () -> {
            System.out.println("second ");
        };
        second(r2);
        
        Runnable r3 = () -> {
            System.out.println("third ");
        };
        third(r3);
        
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join(); // wait for this thread to finish before starting #2
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Thread 1 error");
        }
        
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t2.start();
        
        try {
            t2.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Thread 2 error");
        }
        
        Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
        t3.start();
        
        try {
            t3.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Thread 3 error");
        }
    }```
````

Comment: You can't solve it using `join` the threads need to be executed asynchronously. You need to change `first` `second` and `third` methods in a way that will satisfy the requirements. How the threads are started is not something you're allowed to tamper with. A simple google search will show you a bunch of solutions, for example https://hezhigang.github.io/2019/08/08/LeetCode-Concurrency-Print-in-Order/

Comment: You could use signaling between threads such as described here  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html

Answer (score 4):

A much easier way would be to just use `Semaphore` with `run`, `acquire`, `release` methods:

```
class Foo {
    Semaphore runSecond;
    Semaphore runThird;

    public Foo() {
        runSecond = new Semaphore(0);
        runThird = new Semaphore(0);
    }

    public void first(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException {
        printFirst.run();
        runSecond.release();
    }

    public void second(Runnable printSecond) throws InterruptedException {
        runSecond.acquire();
        printSecond.run();
        runThird.release();
    }

    public void third(Runnable printThird) throws InterruptedException {
        runThird.acquire();
        printThird.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Leetcode is for code challenges, so we should not give complete solutions, because that wouldn't then be a challenge for you.

*So here's a hint:* Use two **`CountDownLatch`** objects, one to inform method `second()` that method `first()` is done, the other to inform method `third()` that method `second()` is done. Read the [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to learn how to use it.

While you are reading through the documentation, I recommend you read the [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#package.description), to learn more about what features are available for handling multi-threaded code.

---

**UPDATE**

To better understand the challenge, assume that Leetcode is using a class like this to test the `Foo` class.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> call(foo::first, "first,"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> call(foo::second, "second,"));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> call(foo::third, "third."));
        
        // Start threads out of order, with delay between them, giving each thread
        // enough time to complete, if not adequately coded to ensure execution order.
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        t3.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        t1.start();
        
        // Wait for threads to complete
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t1.join();
        
        // At this point, the program output should be "first,second,third."
    }
    interface FooMethod {
        public void call(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException;
    }
    private static void call(FooMethod method, String text) {
        try {
            method.call(() -> System.out.print(text));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**You cannot modify this code**, as it is hidden from you. You have to somehow add code to the `Foo` class to ensure the 3 `Runnable` objects are called in the correct order.

Simply adding `Thread.sleep()` calls to the 3 methods is not the right solution, since this should run regardless of how long of a delay might be added between thread starts by this test below.

You have to use some kind of thread synchronization feature, e.g. [monitors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), [Locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html), or [Synchronizers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#package.description).

Comment: I saw dozens of solutions to this problem. They are posted on LeetCode in the comments section. That was not my question. I am trying to understand why the Runnable object is passed to each function and how to make the Thread.join version work. And why wouldn't the Thread.join be the right way to sequence the threads one after another.

Comment: @user1385969 *"why the Runnable object is passed to each function"* Because the 3 methods will be called with 3 different `Runnable` objects by 3 different threads, and the challenge is to make sure they are called in the correct order. *"how to make the Thread.join version work"* Since the creation of threads is not part of the challenge, why would that even matter? *"why wouldn't the Thread.join be the right way"* Because the challenge is to modify that `Foo` code, specifically those 3 methods, so that an unseen framework that behaves as described will call the `run()` the the right order.

Comment: @user1385969 `Runnable` is just used to pass a function that prints, it has nothing to do with threads, they are not used to start new threads as you did in your code . Perhaps that's what confuses you?